# how to redirect from a directory to a file that has the same name as the directory (if it exists)?

Tags: .htaccess

Imagine: there is example.com/test (directory), and there is example.com/test.html (file)
How to make it so that the link example.com/test opens exactly the file, and not the directory (it is desirable that there is no .html in the address bar)?

I try this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.html -f
RewriteRule .+ /$0.html [L]
```

but it redirects me to `example.com/home/a0987901/domains/example.com/public_html/test/`, but not `example.com/test`.

Comment: @anubhava, yes. I try this:

DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.html -f
RewriteRule .+ /$0.html  [L]

but it redirects me to example.com/home/a0987901/domains/example.com/public_html/test/, but not example.com/test

Comment: Is that all in your .htaccess or you have other rules as well?

Comment: yes, is that all

Comment: Can you test with this URL `example.com/test/` ?

Comment: Not sure how exactly `$0` works, the manual says `$N` was the reference to the N-th group of the matched pattern, but a "zero-th" group is not a thing, so I can only assume this is supposed to be the full input string(?). Can you try `RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]` instead, and see if that changes anything?